# How to setup a docker swarm cluster with AWS ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cluster-computing, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am getting the bellow error. while creating and running container in swarm cluster.

```
  Creating network "ubuntu_default" with the default driver
        ERROR: 500 Internal Server Error: failed to parse pool request 
    for address space "GlobalDefault" pool "" subpool "": 
    cannot find address space GlobalDefault 
    (most likely the backing datastore is not configured)
```

The steps I followed.

1. Created a One VPC and added a security group with allowing all the port numbers.
2. Created a 3 ubuntu machine in AWS (manager, slave1,slave2)
3. First started the Consul node with the below command

   docker run --restart=unless-stopped -d -p 8500:8500 -h consul1 progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
4. Then started a swarm manger on the same machine

   docker run --restart=unless-stopped -d -p 3375:2375 swarm manage consul://172.31.17.163:8500
5. Then added the 2 slaves to it

   docker -H=tcp://slave1ip:2375 --restart=unless-stopped run -d swarm join --advertise=slave1ip:2375 consul://172.31.17.163:8500

   docker -H=tcp://slave2ip:2375 --restart=unless-stopped run -d swarm join --advertise=slave2ip:2375 consul://172.31.17.163:8500
6. Added consul store in swarm manger machine

   DOCKER_OPTS="--cluster-store=consul://172.31.17.163:8500 --cluster-advertise=eth0:2375 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

> docker info

```
Containers: 8
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 6
Images: 4
Server Version: swarm/1.1.3
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 ip-172-31-19-203: slave1ip:2375
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 4
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 1.018 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.13.0-74-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-03-29T11:32:39Z
 ip-172-31-42-220: slave2ip:2375
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 4
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 1
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 1.018 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=native-0.2, kernelversion=3.13.0-74-generic, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-03-29T11:32:21Z
Plugins: 
 Volume: 
 Network: 
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-74-generic
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 2.035 GiB
Name: 257d542e5b26
```

> export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.31.17.163:3375
>
> docker run hello-world

it was excuting perfectly. and I can see the containers creating slaves with spread strategy

Now I just try to create

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
       web:
            image: busybox
```

> docker-compose up

this says the following error.

```
 Creating network "ubuntu_default" with the default driver
    ERROR: 500 Internal Server Error: failed to parse pool request 
for address space "GlobalDefault" pool "" subpool "": 
cannot find address space GlobalDefault 
(most likely the backing datastore is not configured)
```

It giving the same error for

> docker network create -d overlay myapp

so the problem is , this is not creating overlay network , with my current configuration.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: I posted this same questions on docker swarm issues. and I got the Answer
https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2047

The Mistake I did, I didnt add this Config in all the slave nodes

DOCKER_OPTS="--cluster-store=consul://172.31.17.163:8500 --cluster-advertise=eth0:2375 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"